# jQuery with php variable

Tags: php, jquery

i'm having troubles getting this code to work. 
I wanna try and get the info from the database( which works) and put it inside some buttons, and then, when clicking each button i wanna make another 2 divs visible from the same table.

The problem is that only the first button has the fade animation but when clicking the next ones nothing happens. I don't really know how to make each and every one of the buttons have the fade thing effect.
Please help !

```
    $outputList .= '

       <div align="center">
      <table width="750" border="0">
      <tr>
    <td><table width="300" border="0">
    < tr>
    <td width="300" valign="top" id="parent" heith="25px"><a href="#" class="button">' .     $titlu . '</a>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td><table width="750" border="0">
          <tr class="dar" width="300" height="auto" id="descript" border="0">
       <td>' . $descriere. '</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="dac" width="750" height="700" id="video">Video<img src="images.png" width="430" height="157" /></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
   </table>

   </div>';
      }

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".button").click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
        } else {
            $(this).next().hide(); 
        }
      });
     });
   </script>

    <div>
     <?php echo "$outputList"; ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: what is the `}` doing after the `</div>';` ? you getting any errors in console? error logs?

Comment: why do you call next()?

Comment: the } after the div is from a while statement .. I use the while to get data from database an put it inside $outputList.. I call next because the I iwanna show/hide the next thing right after that

Comment: oh and i wanna tell you guys.. i wanna have a different class for every button and that doesn't seem to be possible.. i.e. i can use class=button'. $id .' and have a unique class for every button but then i don't know how to get the jQuery to recognize every class for every div